# Is it worth to build a web application combining AngularJs and ReactJs components

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I have web application that is written in AngularJs 1.x  so i have decided to convert it into either AngularJs2 or ReactJs+AngualrJs2. Reason to choosed ReactJs was that it is rendered faster than AngualrJs and i choosed AnguarJs was that it's two way data binding and i can keep my legacy model as it is and data bind into ReactJs components.I prefer AngualrJs data model over [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/).I am deciding to  create reuslable HTML components in ReactJs and bind AngularJs model data into it.

**Sample Code Snippet using AngualrJs + ReactJs**

```
angular.module('app').directive('greeting',[function(){
    return {
        restrict:'AE',
        scope:{name:'@'},
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs){
            var GreetingSection = React.createClass({displayName: 'Greeting',
                render: function() {
                    var message = "Good morning " + this.props.data.name + ", how are you?";
                    return React.createElement('div', {className: "greeting"},message);
                }
            });
            React.renderComponent(GreetingSection({data:scope}), elem[0]);
        }
    };
}]);
```

My questions are,

1. Are there any performance benefits if i combined AngualrJs(2.x or 1.x) with ReactJs components?
2. Can i achieve faster rendering using AngularJs 2.x without ReactJs?

Please help me to take an decision.

Comment: Angular 2 is not backward compatible, if you have an app in AngularJS you'll have to rewrite it again in Angular 2. ie you won't be able to use a lot of code as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer generally

### Analysis :

Note : i have used both

Remember on all performance post on internet there is MICRO seconds difference & people start shouting "this is fast".."that is slow" ... you could notice.Both are having cutthroat performance

so if you really worried about performance then try to categorize your app based on below criteria .

so that you don't mess up loading **"angular 10 libs" + "react 10 libs" = 20 libs** on ui , without analyzing

**Angular category**

1. Famous for two way data binding
2. Best for lots of data computation on UI Eg -
   `rate * quantity = amount`
3. Its stubborn(typed lang,framework driven) for creating components.

**React category**

1. Famous for component simplicity & rendering
2. Best for lots of visual changes on UI Eg : adding bulk markers on map
3. Worst for lots of data computation on UI Eg -
   `rate * quantity = amount`.So if you miss 1 `setState()` and final computation will be wrong

### Confusion :

So if person wants to use both then person have not defined his use case clearly,As after using both libraries he will be adding extra dozens of libraries which will slow down app from other side

So if person chooses only 1 than he is on very much right direction & his use case falls in above 2 categories

### Note :

The tipping decision to choose 1 from both will largely depend on **how Massively, Badly, Largely, Mostly you be using two way data binding feature/setState**.
As in react for two way data binding you have to write `setState()` , where as in angular you don't have such tension.

so if you have very less ui data computations like 2..3 per form than react is fine else straight away choose angular

Eg : suppose if you have 40 computations in local state like `rate * quantity = amount` so in react you have to write `setState()` for 40 times .so you miss 1 setState and final numbers will be wrong.So its better to use angular in this case

Eg : suppose if you have 40 computations in redux state .the it will be BULL**IT to write 40*50 extra coding lines.

For 1 computation

In angular you will write `rate * quantity = amount` **total 1 line in angular**.

But react Action 4 lines , Reducer 5 lines ,Component 3 lined **total 12 lines in react.**

### Advice :

If you are not sure,then choose angular as it is having all extreme case features

### Conclusion :

Its Not worth combining angular with react

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about using both together but yes 
You should play around with these together and see if you can improve your application.
Reactjs will help you to improve faster rendering but angular js 2.x will help you to improve Performance

Comment: Your answer needs some sources, those are quite bold claims.